# API HOST name from env variable node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I have got a react app where I need to dynamically pass the API HOST name from environment `(docker run --env API_HOST=localhost`)

I'm using a child process in gulp to run 'node node.js'

```
//run npm install then node app   
cp.spawn('npm install' ,{cwd:NODE_APP_FOLDER,env:process.env}, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }

  var server = cp.spawn('node', ['app.js'], { 
    cwd: NODE_APP_FOLDER, 
    env: {
      API_HOST:'localhost'
    }
  });
}
```

but in my code within the app `process.env.API_HOST` return `undefined`

Any help would be much appreciated